# How to check if email is already in use and if email is in bad format prior to creating the user via Firebase (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, email, error-handling, firebase-authentication

is it possible to check if an email address is already in use before calling the `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createEmail...`

I have multiple sign up view controllers which users will have to enter an email address, create user name, then enter their name and create a password in that exact order. However these are all separate view controllers besides the name and password ( that one is together in one).

I would like the user to know if the email address entered is in the correct format and or if it is already in use. The only way I figured out how to do it is after the user goes through all of the view controllers then clicks the sign up button which checks for ALL errors.

This is the code I have for the final view controller which creates the user after all the steps are completed ( sign up button pressed)

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: createEmail as! String, password: password as! String ) { (user, error) in

        // stop activity indicator
        self.nextButton.setTitle("Sign Up", for: .normal)
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        if error == nil && user != nil {
            print("User Created!")
            // If user is created go to Welcome Page
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToWelcomeVC", sender: self)
            } else {
        // If there is an error creating an account
            print("error creating User: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            print(error!._code)
            self.handleError(error!)
            return
```

This is the code I am playing around with for the email view controller. ( continue button pressed) ** do not mind to much of the AuthErrorCode, I was trying to find a way to call that and incorporate it into the error checking.. does not seem to be working to well for me.

```
// TODO check email
   let invalidEmail = AuthErrorCode.invalidEmail
   let emailTaken = AuthErrorCode.emailAlreadyInUse

    }

    if (emailTextField.text?.isEmpty)! {
        print("textField is empty")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message: "Please enter an email address.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: " Try Again", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCreateUsernameVC", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/Auth#/c:objc(cs)FIRAuth(im)fetchSignInMethodsForEmail:completion:). It provides an API to look up all the associated methods of sign-in for the provided email. If the email is not registered, you will get back an empty array.